# How can I make the responses show in different order?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the answers to appear messy along with the question, so the answers don't always look the same, but the answers seem messy with the question.

**example in question 1 Who is really a chef? respond, 'Monica', 'Chandler', 'Rachel', 'Ross' I want those responses to be displayed randomly as' Chandler', 'Ross'' Rachel ',' Monica 'or' Monica ',' Rachel ',' Ross', 'Chandler'**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#remaining-time").hide();
  $("#start").on("click", trivia.startGame);
  $(document).on("click", ".option", trivia.guessChecker);
});

var trivia = {
    correct: 0,
    incorrect: 0,
    unanswered: 0,
    currentSet: 0,
    // "seen" property will keep track of the seen questions so we don't re-display them again
    seen: [],
    // Update: limit the number of question per game. Usong a property so you can change its value whenever you want to change the limit
    limit: 4,
    timer: 20,
    timerOn: false,
    timerId: "",
    // questions options and answers data
    questions: {
      q1: "Who is actually a chef?",
      q2: "What does Joey love to eat?",
      q3: "How many times has Ross been divorced?",
      q4: "How many types of towels does Monica have?",
      q5: "Who stole Monica's thunder after she got engaged?",
      q6: "Who hates Thanksgiving?",
      q7: "Who thinks they're always the last to find out everything?"
    },
    options: {
      q1: ["Monica", "Chandler", "Rachel", "Ross"],
      q2: ["Fish", "Apples", "Oranges", "Sandwhiches"],
      q3: ["5", "2", "1", "3"],
      q4: ["3", "8", "11", "6"],
      q5: ["Rachel", "Phoebe", "Emily", "Carol"],
      q6: ["Joey", "Chandler", "Rachel", "Ross"],
      q7: ["Ross", "Phoebe", "Monica", "Chandler"]
    },
    answers: {
      q1: "Monica",
      q2: "Sandwhiches",
      q3: "3",
      q4: "11",
      q5: "Rachel",
      q6: "Chandler",
      q7: "Phoebe"
    },
    // random number generator
    random: (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min,
    startGame: function() {
      trivia.currentSet = 0;
      // set "seen" to an empty array for a new game
      trivia.seen = [];
      trivia.correct = 0;
      trivia.incorrect = 0;
      trivia.unanswered = 0;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      $("#game").show();
      $("#results").html("");
      $("#timer").text(trivia.timer);
      $("#start").hide();
      $("#remaining-time").show();
      trivia.nextQuestion();
    },
    nextQuestion: function() {
      trivia.timer = 10;
      $("#timer").removeClass("last-seconds");
      $("#timer").text(trivia.timer);
      if (!trivia.timerOn) {
        trivia.timerId = setInterval(trivia.timerRunning, 1000);
      }
      // get all the questions
      const qts = Object.values(trivia.questions);
      // init the random number
      let rq = null;
      // firstly, if no more questions to show set rq to -1 to let us know later that the game has finished 
      // Update: checking if we reached the "limit"
      if (trivia.seen.length >= trivia.limit) rq = -1
      else {
        // otherwise generate a random number from 0 inclusive to the length of the questions - 1 (as array indexing starts from 0 in JS) also inclusive
        do {
          // generate a random number using the newly added "random" method
          rq = trivia.random(0, qts.length - 1);
        } while (trivia.seen.indexOf(rq) != -1); // if the question is already seen then genrate another number, do that till we get a non-seen question index
        // add that randomly generated index to the seen array so we know that we have already seen it
        trivia.seen.push(rq);
        // increment the counter
        trivia.counter++;
      }
      // current question index is the generated random number "rq"
      trivia.currentSet = rq;
      var questionContent = Object.values(trivia.questions)[rq];
      $("#question").text(questionContent);
      var questionOptions = Object.values(trivia.options)[trivia.currentSet];
      $.each(questionOptions, function(index, key) {
        $("#options").append(
          $('<button class="option btn btn-info btn-lg">' + key + "</button>")
        );
      });
    },
    timerRunning: function() {
      if (
        trivia.timer > -1 &&
        // all the questions have already been seen
        // Update: now we check against the limit property
        trivia.seen.length < trivia.limit
    ) {
      $("#timer").text(trivia.timer);
      trivia.timer--;
      if (trivia.timer === 4) {
        $("#timer").addClass("last-seconds");
      }
    } else if (trivia.timer === -1) {
      trivia.unanswered++;
      trivia.result = false;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $("#results").html(
        "<h3>Out of time! The answer was " +
        Object.values(trivia.answers)[trivia.currentSet] +
        "</h3>"
      );
    }
    // if the game ended as we know that -1 means no more questions to display
    else if (trivia.currentSet === -1) {
      $("#results").html(
        "<h3>Thank you for playing!</h3>" +
        "<p>Correct: " +
        trivia.correct +
        "</p>" +
        "<p>Incorrect: " +
        trivia.incorrect +
        "</p>" +
        "<p>Unaswered: " +
        trivia.unanswered +
        "</p>" +
        "<p>Please play again!</p>"
      );
      $("#game").hide();
      $("#start").show();
    }
  },
  guessChecker: function() {
    var resultId;
    var currentAnswer = Object.values(trivia.answers)[trivia.currentSet];
    if ($(this).text() === currentAnswer) {
      //turn button green for correct
      $(this).addClass("btn-success").removeClass("btn-info");
      trivia.correct++;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $("#results").html("<h3>Correct Answer!</h3>");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("btn-danger").removeClass("btn-info");

      trivia.incorrect++;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $("#results").html(
        "<h3>Better luck next time! " + currentAnswer + "</h3>"
      );
    }
  },

  guessResult: function() {
    // no need to increment trivia.currentSet anymore
    $(".option").remove();
    $("#results h3").remove();
    trivia.nextQuestion();
  }
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header text-center clearfix">
    <h1 class="text-muted">Friends trivia game</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="game">
        <h2>FRIENDS Trivia Game</h2>
        <p id="remaining-time" class="lead">Remaining Time: <span id="timer"></span></p>
        <p id="question" class="lead"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="results">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="choices" class="text-center">
        <button id="start" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Start Game</button>
        <div id="options">

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: Just use a [shuffle function](https://javascript.info/task/shuffle) around the value of each of your options.

Comment: @elersong That's what I suggested in my answer, in fact the answer I posted is basically the first solution given in your link. It's not perfectly random like the link points out, but it does the trick for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Where you begin adding answers to the page, try this code instead:

```
$.each(Object.values(trivia.options)[trivia.currentSet].sort( () => { 
    return .5 - Math.random(); 
}), key => {
    $("#options").append(
        $('<button class="option btn btn-info btn-lg">' + key + "</button>")
    );
});
```

This is not a secure or efficient way of randomizing an array, but it does the trick for something like this. It just picks a random number between 0 and 1 and subtracts it from 0.5, so the returned number is between -0.5 and 0.5. The `sort` function does the rest.

This whole thing belongs at the end of your `trivia.nextQuestion` function.

This whole thing could be done without jQuery. If you're not using it for any particular reason, it might be worth your while to try this in vanilla JavaScript. To get you started, here's the same chunk of code:

```
const options = document.getElementById("options");
Object.values(trivia.options)[trivia.currentSet].sort( () => { 
    return .5 - Math.random(); 
}).forEach(key => {
    options.innerHTML += `<button class="option btn btn-info btn-lg">${key}</button>';
});
```

And while you're at it, look at whether `trivia.questions`, `trivia.options`, or `trivia.answers` need to be objects, or if arrays would work fine. But that belongs mroe on Code Review...

Comment: I used the code and only numbers appear in the answers.

Comment: There's another way?

Comment: Sorry @DanielLopez I'm not quite sure what you mean, but I meant that you could just forget about `q1` and `q2` etc and just use arrays instead. But that depends on what direction you're going with this so do whatever you think. If you're looking for solid advice on quality code, try posting on Code Review